# `curl --verbose` but without SSL details? (i.e. just HTTP headers)

Tags: http, curl

Calling `-v`/`--verbose` on `curl(1)` will show me the HTTP headers of a request & response (and also tell me if curl is following a redirect). But if the server is over HTTPS/SSL/TLS, then it will also give me several lines about the TLS/SSL connection. I care about the HTTP headers, not the SSL details.

Is it possible to get curl to show me the HTTP headers, and not the SSL connection details?

---

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.83.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.83.1 OpenSSL/3.0.3 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.47.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.12
Release-Date: 2022-05-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

Answer (score 2):

`curl -D - https://uri/` will display the response's headers + body.

Answer (score 2):

`curl -I` performs a HEAD requests and displays headers (there could be no body).

`curl -i` allows to use arbitrary request method, and displays both headers and the body.

From [man curl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html):

```
   -I, --head
          (HTTP  FTP  FILE)  Fetch  the headers only! HTTP-servers feature 
          the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header 
          of a document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays
          the file size and last modification time only.
   
   -i, --include
          Include the HTTP response headers in the output. The HTTP
          response headers can include things like server name, cookies,
          date of the document, HTTP version and more...

          To view the request headers, consider the -v, --verbose option.

          See also -v, --verbose.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -v https://example.com 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep -P '^[<>]'
```

This hides also a bunch of other stuff like IPs, ports etc. but if you're interested only in the headers, it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).